# ANTLR Java 32-bit issue with debugging on Windows 64-bit

Tags: classpath, antlr, java

I'm trying to get debugging working properly for `AST trees` working in `ANTLR`, and I keep getting this same error when I try to debug:

Error occurred during initialization of VM

```
Unable to load native library: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Error: loading: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
```

I have `32-bit and 64-bit Java installed` (reinstalled 32 to be sure), so I'm not sure what it can't find. However, upon checking my `CLASSPATH` environmental variable, it originally was set to a `jre6` folder in ProgFiles(x86), ending up on `QTJava.zip`. Searching now, not only do I not have a `jre6` folder (only the jre7 and jdk folders), but none of these have a `QTJava.zip` in them.

Is this broken `CLASSPATH` to blame for `ANTLR's` issues? I'm new to working with Java, so this is all very foreign to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, here's my installed Java's if it [helps](http://goo.gl/lwbps)

Comment: Exactly *how* are you debugging? Using ANTLRWorks, the Eclipse plugin, a plain-old Java class?